# Haskell a better way a replacing a character in a string

Tags: list, haskell

I made this function

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
replace _ _ [] = []
replace a b (c:r)
    | a == c = b : replace a b r
    | otherwise = c : replace a b r
```

and was looking for a better way to write it when i found this :

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
replace a b  = map $ \c -> if c == a then b else c
```

There not even the third argument written, and i don't understand the $ and the \c symbols, but it work and I want to know what is happening here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `$` operator applies a function to an argument. We can rewrite your example as

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
replace a b  = map (\c -> if c == a then b else c)
```

Pragmatically, Haskellers often use `$` to avoid parentheses. It's rarely used for other reasons.

About the `\c -> ...`: this is an anonymous function, also called a "lambda". It stands for the function taking `c` as argument and returning the `...` part. In your case, the function takes `c` and checks if it's equal to `a`, in which case it returns `b`, otherwise it returns `c`. We could rewrite the code without the lambda as follows:

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
replace a b  = map myFun
   where
   myFun :: Char -> Char
   myFun = \c -> if c == a then b else c
```

or, moving the argument `c` to the left of `=`, as follows:

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
replace a b  = map myFun
   where
   myFun :: Char -> Char
   myFun c = if c == a then b else c
```

About the "missing third argument": the type `Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]` can be read in multiple ways:

- the type of functions taking one argument (`Char`) and returning a function (`Char -> [Char] -> [Char]`)
- the type of functions taking two arguments (`Char` and `Char`) and returning a function (`[Char] -> [Char]`)
- the type of functions taking three arguments (`Char`, `Char`, and `[Char]`) and returning a list (`[Char]`)

All these three interpretations are compatible, thanks to currying. Indeed, the "two arguments" function

```
foo :: A -> B -> B
foo x y = y
```

and the function

```
foo :: A -> B -> B
foo x = id              -- id is the identity function B -> B
```

are the same.

In your example, if you want, you can add the missing argument to both sides of `=` as follows:

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
replace a b xs = map myFun xs
   where
   myFun :: Char -> Char
   myFun c = if c == a then b else c
```

In this expanded code, you can see that `map myFun xs` uses `map` (library function) to apply `myFun` to all the elements of list `xs`, and return the list of all the results.
This effectively achieves the substitution you want.

However, without adding the third argument,

```
replace :: Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]
replace a b = map myFun
   where ...
```

we can still interpret `map myFun` as transforming the function `myFun :: Char -> Char` into a function `[Char] -> [Char]`. The latter is indeed the return type of `replace` if we interpret that as a "two arguments" function. That is, `replace 'a' 'b'` is the function `[Char] -> [Char]` which takes a string and replaces every `'a'` in it with a `'b'`.

Answer (score 4):

> There not even the third argument written. (…)

In Haskell, all functions have only *one* argument. Indeed `Char -> Char -> [Char] -> [Char]` is short for `Char -> (Char -> ([Char] -> [Char]))`, it is thus a function that takes a `Char` and then returns another function. If we apply that function with another `Char`, it returns a function of type `[Char] -> [Char]` that will map a list of `Char`s to a list of `Char`s, and finally if we call that function with a list of `Char`s we get a list of `Char`s.

This thus means that if there are two parameters in the head of the function, that `map $ \c -> if c == a then b else c` should return a function, and that is the case.

> (…) I don't understand the `$` (…) symbols.

The [**`($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) function is defined as:

```
infixr 0 $

($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b
($) f x = f x
```

it is thus function application. The reason why that is used is because it has a precedence of `0`, this thus means that `a $ b x` for example will be evaluated as `a (b x)`, whereas `a b x`, will be evaluated as `(a b) x`. It thus means that the function is equivalent to `map (\c -> if c == a then b else c)`.

> I don't understand (…) the \c symbols

That is a *lambda expression*. It is a function that takes as input a variable `c` and maps this on the part at the right of the arrow (`->`). Here it thus means that it maps a `Char`acter `c` to `b` if `c == a`; and otherwise it returns `c`.